# get content_for from render_to_string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The render_to_string used to execute erb view. The erb view make call content_for. Is it possible and how to get content_for data from scope where render_to_string is called?

test.rb:

```
string = render_to_string partial: "test_view", :layout => false
data = get_content_for_data( :data ) # "some data ..."
```

test_view.erb:

```
<% content_for :data do %>
    some data ...
<% end %>
```

And reverse question. How to put content_for data from same scope to erb view?

test.rb:

```
data = "some data ..."
put_content_for_data( :data, data )
string = render_to_string partial: "test_view", :layout => false
```

test_view.erb:

```
<%= yield :data %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is can be said as solution as workaround. Use the special layout view that forward `content_for` data to controller:

The content_for to controller forwarder (layout view):

fetch_content_for.erb

```
<%= yield %>
<% fetch_content_for :data, content_for( :data ) %>
```

The controller:

test.rb:

```
helper_method :fetch_content_for

def fetch_content_for( tag, content )
  @content_for[tag] = content
end
```

Render with content_for fetching, somewhere in controller:

```
string = render_to_string
  partial: "any_view",
  layout: "fetch_content_for"
data = @content_for[:data]
```

And reverse question. Put fetched content_for data to erb view:

test_view.erb:

```
<%= @content_for[:data] # put fetched data %>
<%= yield :data         # put normal content_for data %>
```